# How can I use a vuex store in a plugin?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

In my Vue plugin, I am passing the Vuex store as part of the options during the `install`

**main.ts (main project):**

```js
import store from "./store/";

Vue.use(Camera, { store });

new Vue({
    router,
    store,
    render: h => h(AppName)
}).$mount("#app");
```

**main.ts (in plugin):**

```js
export default {
    install(Vue, options: any) {
        var result = options.store.getters['getFeaturesList']; // result is the correct object I need

        Vue.prototype.$myStore = function() {
            return options.store;
        }

        Vue.component("camera-control", Camera);
    }
}
```

However, when I try and access the prototype property in a component inside the plugin, it's telling me that `Property '$myStore' does not exist on type 'Camera'`

**Camera.vue (in plugin)**

```js
public getFeatureList() {
    const featuresList = this.$myStore().getters["getFeaturesList"]; //error
}
```

I am assuming that the instances are not the same in the install function and the component, hence why it's giving me the error, but I need to be able to access the main project's store from the plugin - is this even possible? How would I get access to the store?

Comment: You're confusing compile and runtime errors. The problem is TypeScript typing. The question doesn't even mention TypeScript. Also, it's `myStore` in one place and `$myStore` in another, so there should be runtime error, too.

Comment: @Estus Flask Thanks for pointing out the typo, I must have deleted the $ when formatting the question.  I don't understand why the question should have mentioned TypeScript, or even what the problem is. Can you expand a bit please?

Comment: The error you mentioned is Typescript compilation error (it mentions *type 'Camera'*, JS doesn't have the concept of types). This is exclusively TS problem. The error could be silenced with `this['$myStore']().getters.getFeaturesList`. Providing a correct type is much more preferable.

Answer (score 1):

> Property '$myStore' does not exist on type 'Camera'

is TypeScript compilation error. It doesn't mean that `$myStore` cannot be accessed but that it wasn't typed properly; typing system is unaware that Vue instances have `$myStore` property.

As [the documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/typescript.html#Augmenting-Types-for-Use-with-Plugins) explains, Vue type declarations should have been extended for new properties that are added by a plugin:

```
// plugin.d.ts
import Vue from 'vue';
import { Store } from 'vuex';

declare module 'vue/types/vue' {
  interface Vue {
    $store: Store<any>;
  }
}
```

`plugin.d.ts` should be imported either automatically from typings path or manually:

```
import "./plugin";
```

Comment: I was completely unaware of this part of the documentation, and it all makes sense however, I've made the changes you've suggested, but when running, `this.$store` (and to avoid conflicting with any existing variable named that I also tried with `this.$myStore` with the same result) is always `undefined`. The typing worked though, Intellisense shows the correct type when I hover over it.

I can access `this.$parent.$store` inside my plugin component - but is accessing this considered bad practise at all?

Comment: Yes, $parent is a bad practice and defies the reason to change the proto, to make a property available in all components. $myStore should be available in all components. If it's not, this means that a component derives from another Vue copy or something was done wrong. The question doesn't contain how the plugin is used. Please, provide a way to replicate the problem.

Comment: I've got two example repos which show the same issue:
Main project: https://github.com/shepherdnick/so_main
Plugin project: https://github.com/shepherdnick/so_plugin

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense. As noted, this can happen if there's another Vue copy, so `Vue.prototype` isn't the same for some components. The issue is very specific to how your projects are organized. `"so_plugin": "file:../so_plugin"` local dep results in nested node_modules that cannot be deduped and makes a plugin to use its own Vue, like `node_modules/so_plugin/node_modules/vue`. There are several ways to handle unpublished deps correctly. Try local NPM registry or something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47420244

Comment: As a note, it may be inconvenient to have $myStore as getter function and call it every time. Can be made a property with defineProperty or simply `Vue.prototype.$myStore = options.store`.

Comment: Thanks for your help with this topic - I'll attempt the local NPM registry - looks like there are a few options.  RE your note, I had already done that - I'd left it as a function from example code I was following. One final thing: is it generally bad practise to be trying to achieve what I'm achieving? I am covering previous developer's implementation that was entirely un-maintainable and did not allow for a pleasant development experience, but considering the amount of effort I've had to put in, I'm even wondering if I should just refactor out the Vuex requirement entirely.

Comment: Depends on your case if it's bad. Plugin design is ok but it's redundant to expose a store with $myStore - Vuex already does this with $store. And if Vuex isn't needed for anything but this plugin then it's a total overkill for simple reactivity such as isAlarmFeature.

Comment: I ended up using the webpack config described in this post: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/4271#issuecomment-585299391 - needing to be able to develop, and also run it, just adding a "peerDependencies" was not enough to get the whole development environment working properly.